# Pandas dataframe apply to get a list throws error

Tags: python, pandas, apply, pickle

I am running Python 3.6.x and pandas version 0.19.2. I am trying to create a list for each entry in a dataframe as below. This example works.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'names':['a', 'b', 'c'], 'year_min':[2001, 2010, 2005], 'year_max':[2018, 2019, 2017]})
start_year = 2017
df['years'] = df.apply(lambda x: list(range(max(x['year_min'],start_year), x['year_max']+1)), axis=1)

df
Out[37]: 
  names  year_max  year_min               years
0     a      2018      2001        [2017, 2018]
1     b      2019      2010  [2017, 2018, 2019]
2     c      2017      2005              [2017]
```

Unfortunately, when I try the same line of code for the [dataframe in this pickle file](https://github.com/zhubarb/Expectation_Maximisation/blob/master/players_2017_2019.p), I get an error, despite the `dtypes` of the two columns still being `int64`. Without doubt, I have messed up some bit of this dataframe, but I have no clue what the problem is (!). Any ideas?

```
players = pd.read_pickle("players_2017_2019.p")
start_year = 2017
players['years']= players.apply(lambda x: list(range(max(x['year_min'],start_year), x['year_max']+1)), axis=1)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...\python36\win64\431\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 4262, in create_block_manager_from_arrays
    blocks = form_blocks(arrays, names, axes)
  File "...\python36\win64\431\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 4339, in form_blocks
    int_blocks = _multi_blockify(int_items)
  File "...\python36\win64\431\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 4408, in _multi_blockify
    values, placement = _stack_arrays(list(tup_block), dtype)
  File "...\python36\win64\431\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 4453, in _stack_arrays
    stacked[i] = _asarray_compat(arr)
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (2) into shape (3)
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):

```
 File "...\python36\win64\431\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2881, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-2-7fc8712b01b0>", line 1, in <module>
    players.apply(lambda x: list(range(max(x['year_min'],start_year), x['year_max']+1)), axis=1)
  File "...\python36\win64\431\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 4152, in apply
    return self._apply_standard(f, axis, reduce=reduce)
  File "...\python36\win64\431\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 4265, in _apply_standard
    result = self._constructor(data=results, index=index)
  File "...\python36\win64\431\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 266, in __init__
    mgr = self._init_dict(data, index, columns, dtype=dtype)
  File "...\python36\win64\431\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 402, in _init_dict
    return _arrays_to_mgr(arrays, data_names, index, columns, dtype=dtype)
  File "...\python36\win64\431\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 5408, in _arrays_to_mgr
    return create_block_manager_from_arrays(arrays, arr_names, axes)
  File "...\python36\win64\431\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 4267, in create_block_manager_from_arrays
    construction_error(len(arrays), arrays[0].shape, axes, e)
  File "...\python36\win64\431\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 4231, in construction_error
    raise ValueError("Empty data passed with indices specified.")
ValueError: Empty data passed with indices specified.
```

**EDIT:**
The issue was solved when I updated my pandas to 0.23.0
Also, the issue is linked to `https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/17892`.

Comment: it worked fine for me!!

Comment: What python and pandas version are you using because your code runs fine on my machine?

Comment: Python 3.6.1, Pandas 0.19.2. The pickled dataframe in github works fine for you?

Comment: yes it works fine for the pickle file from the github

Comment: what is your Pandas version?

Comment: pandas version is 0.23.0

Comment: Works fine for me too - pandas 0.23.0 AND python 3.6.5

Comment: Thanks, let me try to update pandas. if it works (for some reason) after that, i will close the question.